# How to click on a ref in react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a file uploader using react. I want to hide the default file input element and trigger it when user click on a div.

```
    <div style={{position:"relative",width:"500px",height:"300px",background:"gray",marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto",border:"2px 
           dotted white"}}
         onClick={this.clickOnFakeUploader}
    > 
       <div style={{float:"left",marginTop:"100px",width:"100%"}}>
         <h4 style={{color:"white",marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"}}>Drag & Drop Files Here! 
         </h4>
       </div>
   </div>
    
   <label className="btn btn-default" style={{display:"none"}}>
   <input ref={this.fileUploader}  type="file" multiple onChange={this.selectFiles} />
   </label>
      

    this.fileUploader = React.createRef();
    
      this.clickOnFakeUploader = () =>{
    
            this.fileUploader.click();
      }
```

I am getting `TypeError: this.fileUploader.click is not a function` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.fileUploader.current.click()
```

you need to address it with `current`